# Read from memory as read from disk?

Tags: java, python, performance, memory, io

Is there a way we can treat read from memory as read from disk? The issue is, I want to test how much performance gain if I read and process a the same content of a file from memory directly, comparing to on disk I/O. But my code is written in a way to read from disk I/O (e.g. open a file, read from a file and close a file). If there is way we can push a file into local memory and treat the chunk of memory as a file to process, it will be great. Any straightforward solution is appreciated.

BTW, using Java/Python on Linux. :)

Comment: What platform? What language? And yes, it's possible but the actual solution depends on those questions.

Comment: Use a [Ram Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)?

Comment: http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux

Comment: Your choices are tmpfs and /dev/shm, independent of programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're more interested in loading the file into memory and then parsing it, e.g., as opposed to actually storing the file in memory (RAM disk).

You can do this in both Java and Python. Examples:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_entire_file#Python. You can even write functions that accept either a file stream or another type of stream that reads straight from memory, letting the callers of your function decide how to retrieve the data.

However, this indirect way of first reading the file in its entirety (or in large blocks) to memory and then processing memory rarely gives you any real gains. One of the reasons is because while disk I/O *is* really slow, I/O streams in most languages/libraries do buffered reading of the file anyway. So they're already doing this for you.

The cost of file I/O operations is often overestimated while the logic involved in processing the file is underestimated. So I think it's worth profiling your code to see if disk I/O is actually the culprit. A profiler will not only let you be able to tell but also tell you exactly what is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planning to modify file contents prior to serving (e.g. decoding/compression), why not leverage zero-copy NIO transferTo and transferFrom methods for sending the file directly to socket, without even crossing user boundary and doing at the kernel level.

```
    final File inputFile = new File(args[0]);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8083);
    SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    socketChannel.connect(socketAddress);

    long totalBytesTransferred = 0;
    while (totalBytesTransferred < inputFile.length()) {
        long bytesTransferred = fileChannel.transferTo(totalBytesTransferred, inputFile.length()-totalBytesTransferred, socketChannel);
        totalBytesTransferred += bytesTransferred;
    }
```

Zero-copy is available on Linux and its up to 2x faster with lower memory footprint.